# “Could not find stored procedure <procedure name>” error using Python and pyodbc

Tags: python, sql, ssms, pyodbc

Im trying to execute stored procedure using Python and pyodbc

Say, I can run the code below perfectly in Python which means my connection is not wrong

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Employee")
```

but

```
cursor.execute("EXEC salary_by_year 2006")
```

It printed out "Could not find stored procedure 'salary_by_year'".

However I can run the code just fine in SSMS.

It's likely I can't access stored procedure in Python.

How can I solve that?

Comment: Are you connected to the correct database? Maybe use the fully qualified name database.schema.salary_by_year

Comment: You are right, thank you!